# Ionic 2 Angular 2 Display Data from Array of Objects

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am attempting to create a 'simple' Ionic 2 / Angular 2 Application that provides information to voters from a Google CivicInfo API Call. Users submit their address and a Ionic2/Angular2 service provider takes the form params and creates a url query string. The response is put into an Observable.

CivicInfoProvider.ts

```
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL, { search: params })
.toPromise()
.then(response => response.json() as UserData[], err => console.log(err));
```

With the response as a JSON Observable the user is taken to the Civic Info Listing page where the data is displayed for the user.

CivicInfoList.ts

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private info: CivicInfoProvider ) {
      this.addr.street = this.navParams.get('street');
      this.addr.city = this.navParams.get('city');
      this.addr.state = 'PA';
      this.addr.zip = this.navParams.get('zip');
      this.searchString = this.addr.street + ' ' +
                          this.addr.city + ' ' +
                          this.addr.state + ' ' +
                          this.addr.zip;
      this.userdata = this.info.getCivicInfo(this.searchString);
    }
```

CivicInfoList.html

```
<ion-content padding>

  <h6>Search Results For:</h6>
  {{ (userdata | async)?.normalizedInput?.line1 }}
  {{ (userdata | async)?.normalizedInput?.city }}
  {{ (userdata | async)?.normalizedInput?.state }}
  {{ (userdata | async)?.normalizedInput?.zip }}

  <h6>Election Details:</h6>
  <ion-list lines>
    <ion-item>
      Name: {{ (userdata | async)?.election?.name }}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      Date: {{ (userdata | async)?.election?.electionDay }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <h6>Your Polling Location:</h6>
  <ion-item ngFor="location of userdata.pollingLocations">
    {{ location }}
  </ion-item>

  <h6>Contests:</h6>
  <ion-list lines>
    <ion-item ngFor="contest of userdata.contests, [value]='object'">
        {{ contest }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**MY PROBLEM** :: I CAN NOT figure out how to display the Objects that are stored in arrays *pollingLocations* from the JSON example below. I can display *normalizedInput* ...

In true Angular fashion there are no error messages or cryptic messages that do not lead to any help in documentation or Google searches.

Selectioned API Response

```
{
 "kind": "civicinfo#voterInfoResponse",
 "election": {
  "id": "2000",
  "name": "VIP Test Election",
  "electionDay": "2017-06-06",
  "ocdDivisionId": "ocd-division/country:us"
 },
 "normalizedInput": {
  "line1": "911 Merrybell Lane",
  "city": "Kennett Square",
  "state": "PA",
  "zip": "19348"
 },
 "pollingLocations": [
  {
   "address": {
    "locationName": "KENNETT TOWNSHIP BLDG",
    "line1": "801 BURROWS RUN RD",
    "city": "CHADDS FORD",
    "state": "PA",
    "zip": ""
   },
   "notes": "",
   "pollingHours": "",
   "sources": [
    {
     "name": "Voting Information Project",
     "official": true
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
```

Thanks for Your Help!
[Screen Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVoj2.png)

Comment: It's `*ngFor`, not `ngFor`. And why do you use async everywhere to access the userdata, except there? I wouldn't use async at all: store the actual array in your component, enclose everything into an *ngIf to make sure the content is only displayed when the array is available, and remove the async and the elvis operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your json does not have an array of objects, you should use like this,

```
<ul>
      <li *ng-for="#person of people.pollingLocations">
          {{person.address | json}}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/b7Kgzt?p=preview)